# What makes the PHP function is_readable case-insensitive?

Tags: php, macos, virtualbox

I get different results using `is_readable` on a directory named `folder` given the following two cases :

Case 1: PHP version 5.3.3-7+squeeze14 running on Debian (through a VirtualBox installed on a Mac)

- is_readable('/home/.../`folder`') : 1
- is_readable('/home/.../`Folder`') : 1

Case 2: PHP version 5.3.5-1ubuntu7 running on Ubuntu 11.04 (GNU/Linux 2.6.38-8-server x86_64)

- is_readable('/home/.../`folder`') : 1
- is_readable('/home/.../`Folder`') :

On the first case, I would like to understand why the PHP function `is_readable` is not case-sensitive. I certify that no directory `Folder` (notice the capital F) exists on both cases.

Comment: I would ask the opposite: "What makes the PHP function is_readable case-insensitive?". Because the second behaviour is expected, and the first is strange

Comment: Perhaps `folder` and `Folder` exists both on squeeze, and and debian only `folder` exists?